# AdMob for Android in Eclipse: "The following classes could not be found: - com.admob.android.ads.AdView"

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I've been trying for ages to get AdMob Ads to appear in my app. I followed the AdMob PDF instructions and am stuck at this point: Eclipse, when displaying my main layout XML file in "Graphical Layout" mode, tells me: "The following classes could not be found: - com.admob.android.ads.AdView".

I presumed it had to to with the build path, but from what I can tell the admob...jar file is correctly added as JAR file to the build path for the project and appears under "Referenced Libraries" in the Package Explorer tree of Eclipse.

in the bin folder, however, these classes are not included (should they be?).

Any ideas on how to get eclipse, and the application for that matter, to find these classes?

EDIT: It turns out I get this message on and off for no apparent reason. Playing around with the main XML layout file (the code related to the admob ad) and saving it seems to make the message appear or disappear. However, I don't think it was responsible for the ad not showing. Just make sure the emulator has internet access (not obvious if using WiFi under Linux) and that the layout/positioning is correct.

Comment: It may be a temporary problem and try cleaning all the projects in your **Workspace**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've passed through the same errors, and Nishan's answer was just part of the solution for me.
Don't know if your using a lib with your full app to provide two versions (A free/add supported and a paid one) of your app, each one with a separated project, but both including the app lib.

If this is the case, I solved it by importing the AdMob lib from each of the two main projects, and not from the original app lib. And you need to make sure you select ADD EXTERNAL JAR at Build 
Path Configuratiom, and not just ADD JAR.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a `classpath` issue. This should add the Jar to classpath.

```
 Right click on project > Build Path > Configure Build Path  > Libraries > Add External Jars
```

You may require to rebuild your project. Do a `Project > clean...`

Comment: Hello Nishant, Thanks for your reply. I tried "Add External JARs" as you suggest in stead of "Add JARs" which is what I had done before. Then Clean... . Sadly, that didn't solve my probleme. Am I right in presuming that I need to find the classes included in the JAR file in my bin folder?

Comment: Hi @Chris Dickinson, nope. Adding Jar to build path should be suffice for Eclipse to add the Jar's location to classpath. Can't say what's going wrong. Are you seeing this Error inside the Eclipse? And also, where's the bin file in a Eclipse Java project?

Answer (score 1):

Also double check you have the newest AdMob jars and if you upgraded your AdMob jars make sure you update your code appropriately.  It's pretty simple actually but it will not run adds if you don't update your code appropaitely.  I had to add this to my manifest (you man need to do other steps also so be sure to check the AdMob directions on the upgrade):

```
    <!-- AdMobActivity definition -->
    <activity android:name="com.admob.android.ads.AdMobActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden" />
    <!-- Track Market installs -->
    <receiver android:name="com.admob.android.ads.analytics.InstallReceiver"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
```